# Is 'Boltzon' an accepted name for particles following Maxwell-Boltzmann (MB) statistics?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, soft-question, terminology

In my curriculum during one of my statistical mechanics visiting lecture classes, our teacher was referring comparatively macro particles following [MB statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics) as ["Boltzon"](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=boltzon+statistical). But I have searched Internet, checked few sites and my text book but didn't get any such reference. Is it wrong or correctly identified?

Comment: I have never heard this term, but I guess it's a natural extension to "boson" and "fermion." My advice would be not to use the word without defining it.

Comment: Usually one refers to these as *thermal* particles.

Comment: @KyleKanos can you please give me some details about what do you mean by "thermal" particles?

Comment: The MB distribution depends on temperature (because particles are exchanging energy with the *thermal environment*), that's why they're thermal particles.

Comment: Okay got the meaning. Thank you so much for the answer. :)

Comment: I have heard this term before, but it is not very common.

Comment: Could you ask the lecturer?

Comment: Actually  the problem is I missed the chance to ask him. He was a visiting lecturer and in our institution we dont actually get to know when he comes back. Sometime it's just one day for someone or sometimes it more than once. Sorry :(. But I think as many of the members mentioned it does exist but the problem is am not able to find a proper source of info.

Comment: Some people also use *Boltzmannons*. There is no final consensus on this terminology.

Comment: I came across this term in Richard E. Dickerson's [Molecular Thermodynamics](https://books.google.com/books/?id=9khH5U90Be4C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found theses definitions in "Statistical Thermodynamics" by M.C. Gupta :

- boltzons : particles are distinguishable and there is no restriction of the occupancy of the energy state
- corrected boltzons : particles are indistinguishable

in context of Boltzmann statistics

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I think this book will be available in my library. Have gotta check. But thanks. Info helped me a lot.

Comment: [Multipolarons in a Constant Magnetic Field](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5660) for subtle operating comparisons between bosons and boltzons. The Gupta book is partially on google books